# Windows IPS or a way to drop packets

Tags: inline, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, snort, intrusion-detection

Does anyone know a way to drop packets using Windows, cause I already tried it in many ways.

First I tried it with Snort but there is way to get it inline for Windows use.

My second solution was to use Suricata but also here I ended up the same way as Snort. I can only configure it to run as IDS.

As third I tried TWIDS to make this drop function work but it also gave problems which I cannot find any help with.

Is there any way to set up an IPS or some software to drop packets ?